# Excel function within a function

Tags: excel

I'm sorry if this is the wrong site (and if it is can you direct me to a better site to ask this question).

Determine total number of cities listed for each province/territory.

So for example if there was:

```
Toronto   ON   City
Montreal  QC   City
Ottawa    ON   City
Vancouver BC   City
Calgary   AB   Town
```

Workings:

I want to determine how many ON cities there are (there are 2).

So I was thinking I would do:

> =IF(B1:B5="ON",COUNTIF(C1:C5,"city"),0)

But I get an error. So I am not sure what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the city/province unique, no duplicates? If so: `COUNIFS(B:B,"ON")`  If not and you want unique it will require an array formula.

Comment: use countifs which will allow you to use multiple criteria:  =COUNTIFS(B:B,"ON",C:C,"City")

Comment: Thank you Sorceri that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B5, "ON",C1:C5,"city")
```

Comment: Hello Sorceri. I can honestly say that I didn't see it, if you want you can post your comment as an answer and I will delete this one and upvote yours. I apologise if you feel I've copied you.

Comment: In fact, I've just gone and upvoted your three top answers, so your +30 rep should more than cover what you lost here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B100="ON")*(C1:C100="City"))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B5, "ON")
```

Comment: But what if Ottawa was a town? Then that wouldn't work since it would say 2 despite there only being 1 city.